# Multiple (de)serialize errors when sending pictures of screen over TCP (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, tcp

So a little bit background here:
I was working on a software that share screen from users to another user.

I was using Serialize to send the data (pictures) to the server and Deserialize them but it basically throws lots of errors, stuffs like: "Binary stream does not contain a valid binaryheader", "The input stream is not a valid binary format", "Unable to translate bytes [E7] at index 0 from specified code page to Unicode".

Here's the Serialize code:

```
Try
        Dim bf As BinaryFormatter
        ns = client.GetStream
        bf = New BinaryFormatter
        bf.Serialize(ns, Desktop)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
```

The deserialize one:

```
Try
        ns = clientList(0).listClient.GetStream
        Dim bf As BinaryFormatter
        bf = New BinaryFormatter
        PictureBox1.Image = bf.Deserialize(ns)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
```

Comment: Could you provide more of your code, at least code that can be pasted and compiled.

Comment: Yeah I can!

Server: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vcN90p1Wwkd9IKgXn705PYtCf840H3oY/view?usp=sharing

ClassForServer (This is attached to the server as a class): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s7cnxOiSPbPgH3YpA5pIwqO8Aa0f0NAJ/view?usp=sharing

Client: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12n6bCFuTYqYNehBGZY0lvjnOFNvOntM9/view?usp=sharing

Thanks a lot, I was waiting for someone to reply :D

Comment: I created a 1 to 1 TCP server/client screen sending before and it worked. But this time I created multi server/client one and it didn't work at all. Weird :/

Comment: Your last comment seems like very important information! Could you describe your setup when you have failure? That is, how many clients . servers running, where they are running, on what ports they are comminicating, etc.